# How can I prevent select-deleting part of a string in an input while still allowing the user to write the rest

Tags: jquery, css

I have an input field that is hidden until the user makes a `select` selection. This selection causes the input to partially be filled in.

```
$('#manufacturer').on('change', function() {
    $('#manf_id').val('');
    $('#manufacturerInput').val('');
    if ($(this).val() == 'other') {
        $('#next').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-secondary').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#manufacturerInput').prop('disabled', false).attr('placeholder', 'enter');
    } else {
        $('#manufacturerInput').prop('disabled', true).attr('placeholder', '');
        $('#next').removeClass('btn-secondary').addClass('btn-primary').prop('disabled', false);

        var short = $(this).val().substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
        $('#manf_id').val(short + '_');
    }
});
```

So when the user sees the input field `#manf_id`, the default string in the input is ie. SONY_ and they should be able to add something to create a manf_id like SONY_playstation. The user must not be able to backspace further than playstation so that SONY_ is always there.

```
$("#manf_id").on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length < 5) {
        if (e.which === 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

This works great. The problem is that the user can double click or CTRL/CMD+A and delete the entire string.

I have found css and jQuery ways to prevent selection, but that also prevents clicking in and writing (no prompt).

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Opera and Firefox */
}

<input class="form-control noselect" type="text" placeholder="ID" id="manf_id"/>
```

Is there a solution to prevent the user select-deleting part of, or the entire string (including what they wrote), while allowing backspace to a certain character (as above) and also allowing writing in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way would be set the input value to what you want to be when its length is too short, like so:

```
$("#manf_id").on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length < 5) {
        $(this).val("SONY_")
    }
});
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of this. What it basically does is if someone deletes the entire string, their next keypress puts the prepend SONY_ before anything they write. Cheers!